# Toast Android 11 customization

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toast, android-11

In Android 11 `Toast.setView()` is deprecated.
I wanted to now if there is a way to achieve similar results without using `setView()` like custom font, background color, corner radius etc.
Below you can find my current view I was using in `setView()`.

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
app:cardElevation="0dp"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/primary_dark"
android:alpha="0.9"
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/radius_toast">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toast_dark_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/height_toast"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/radius_toast"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/radius_toast"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="@font/playfair_display_regular"
        tools:text="Custom toast text"
        android:textColor="@color/primary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_regular_14sp" />
</FrameLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: Why does this need to be a `Toast`? Can you simply have it be part of your layout and animate its visibility? What is the *specific* functionality unique to `Toast` that you need?

Comment: Well, if I could add it as a part of my layout I would. I mainly use `Toasts` for error messages and small notifications. This is basically what these are for.

Comment: You can add error messages and small notifications to your layout. For example, wrap your layout in a `ConstraintLayout` and add the error messages and small notifications as children, with a bit of elevation (to float over the main layout content). What is the *specific* functionality *unique* to `Toast` that you need?

Comment: The fact that I don't have to modify 20 layout files and add additional unnecessary depth layer to each of them.

Comment: Then create your own `Dialog` class that displays what you want how you want it, and show and hide your custom `Dialog` in lieu of a `Toast`.

Comment: If a Snackbar is an option(https://material.io/develop/android/components/snackbars), maybe try it. It can be fully customized.